# Realm Swift iOS - Can't Set Primary Key

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'll try to explain my scenario as short as possible, I have read some comments on Realm GitHub Repo about this issue:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason:
>   'Can't set primary key property 'id' to existing value 'xxxxxxx'.

Here's my issue:

I got two classes.

**Appointment Model Class**

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Appointment: Object {

    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var user_id: String?
    dynamic var profile_id: String?

    let mainMeeting = List<Meeting>()
    let meetingsWithOtherInfo = List<Meeting>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

**Meeting Model Class**

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Meeting: Object {

    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var name: String?
    dynamic var created_at: String?

    // other info
    dynamic var restaurant_venue: String?

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

I am fetching the **Appointments** from my server API like this

```
for fetchedAppointment in allAppointmentsFromAlamofire {
    let existingAppointment: Results<(Appointment)>! = realm.objects(Appointment).filter("id = \(fetchedAppointment["id"]!)")

    let newAppointment: Appointment = Appointment()
    newAppointment.id = fetchedAppointment["id"]! as! Int
    ....

    // add data to Meeting connected to Appointment
    let newMeeting = Meeting()
    newMeeting.id = fetchedAppointment["meetings"]["id"]! as! Int
    ...

    // update or add new entry
    try! realm.write {
        print("NEW APPOINTMENT: \(newAppointment)")
        realm.add(newAppointment, update: existingAppointment.count == 0 ? false : true)
    }
}
```

The error comes out whenever the program is trying to update existing entry in realm - whenever the existingAppointment is 1. the workaround here, from what I've read from Github Realm is to delete the **override static func primaryKey()** in Meeting Class.

There is no issue if I am just adding new entries to Appointment, but again, the issue comes out if I will be updating, and the issue goes away if I remove the primaryKey() in Meeting Class ---- BUT, in other screens of my app, I really need to have that primaryKey() in Meeting Class.

My wild guess here is that every time that I need to update entries in Appointment, I should update too the Meeting.

So, the question is: why is this happening? Is my wild guess correct? Any other way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to update the newAppointment object with a value that is not its primary key.

```
realm.add(newAppointment, update: existingAppointment.count == 0 ? false : true)
```

Instead, Realm is expecting you to provide the key for that object so that it can update the specified object.

It looks like you are setting the key value here, which is what you should use for your update.

```
let newAppointment: Appointment = Appointment()
newAppointment.id = fetchedAppointment["id"]! as! Int
```

[Realm documentation on updating with keys.](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#updating-objects)

Comment: You got a point in there, I feel like this answer is correct. Let me try my quick and dirty solution: which is if existingAppointment.count != 0, then delete the entry and then re-add the entry. In that case, I'm updating the entry but by deleting the existing. If you got a better way than this, please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the update argument of `add(:_, update: _)` to `false` if you provide a new object. If your model has a primary key and you want to create or update, you can pass `true` and Realm will automatically figure out whether an object with the same primary key is already managed in the database or not.

Comment: I understand all of that. I already solved the issue by putting a dirty workaround: delete the primaryKey() function in my Meeting model, and I am deleting the entries if I need to update. So I update by: deleting and re-adding. I would like to know 'how to update the Appointment and it's meeting lists properly'.